# Extend a Objective C extension to swift class

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift2

I am suppose to extend a objective C class in swift which has a class extension in different header file with +Protected. The same is implemented in one .m file as usual.

But my problem is If i subclass this class I cannot use the variables and cannot call any methods which are private. But in Objective C if I subclass and import the same +Protected.h file in .m file I can use the private vars and methods of the super class. Can anyone show the way to do it I mean subclass and use the private methods and vars of it in swift as we are able to do in Objective C. Example is show below

```
@interface Parent : NSObject 
@end
```

In seperate header file

```
@interface Parent()
@property NSInteger money;

-(void)spend;
@end

#import "Parent+Protected.h"
@implementation Parent 
@end
```

Using other files for new class

```
@interface ObjCChild : Parent
@end

#import "Parent+Protected.h"

@implementation ObjCChild

-(void)spend {
  self.money--;
}

@end
```

I am trying the same in swift

```
class SwiftChild : Parent {
  override func spend () {
    self.money--
 }
}
```

Here only ObjCChild can spend money not swift child(Even it wont get money :) ). Can anyone help swift child.???

Comment: I know its private methods and vars. But is there a way to access as we do in Objective C

Comment: what do you mean swift child cant spend money?  show us how you are actually using the methods you are posting

Comment: Have you tried adding the #import "Parent+Protected.h" to the bridging header so it is exposed to Swift?

Comment: Yes I tried to add but it is coming as the header file not found. Actually I am importing this file from a lib using pods